# Nginx reverse proxy returns incorrect url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following setup:

- public, dynamic IP from my ISP, dynamical DNS let's call it public.org
- Reverse-proxy (nginx,ubuntu 14.04)
- Webservers (nginx,ubuntu 14.04) A,B,C running webapps within my home network, let's call it private.home

My goal is to reach the webservers A.private.home, B.private.home,... from the internet via the reverse-proxy as A.public.org

For server A I have set up the following lines on the reverse proxy:

```
server{

    listen          80;
    server_name     A.public.org;

    location /{
            proxy_pass http://A.private.home;
    }
}
```

if I then navigate to `http://A.public.org` from an outside device, I get a 404, saying that `A.private.home` could (obviously) not be resolved.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I now can provide an anser myself now.

The actual problem was a rewrite happening on A.private.home which rewrote `http://A.private.home` to `https://A.private.home`. Thanks Dinoosh for getting my attention on the settings of the webapp. 
After removing that rewrite, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your domain name is correctly pointed to the server.

use dig command to check your dns record.

`dig a A.public.org`

Comment: Looks good.

    `$ dig A.public.org
    
    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> A.public.org
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40168
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0,        ADDITIONAL: 0

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;A.public.org. IN A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    A.public.org. 58 IN A --somepublicip--

    ;; Query time: 1489 msec
    ;; SERVER: X.X.X.X#53(X.X.X.X)
    ;; WHEN: Tue Mar 17 10:10:33 2015
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60`

Comment: check your nginx access.log and error.log to see if it shows any entries when you go to your site from outside device.

Comment: Hi, access log shows entries correctly `somepublicip --[17/Mar/2015:11:12:07 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/41.0.2272.56 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"`

Comment: can you dig A.private.home from proxy server. If you can try telneting to port 80 of your app servers from proxy server.

Comment: both works well. However I should point out, that `http://A.private.home` automatically redirects to `https://A.private.home` to protect the user's credentials.
(http on the proxy is also just a POC and I will move on to https, as soon as I get things to work properly)